# how do I use variable name in bokeh HoverTool tooltips?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

In Bokeh when using HoverTool, we end up using the "absolute name"

```
    hover = HoverTool()
    hover.tooltips = [
      ('name of salesperson','@name'),
      ('No. of Sales','@sale_num'),
      ('Sales Revenue in USD','@sale_rev')
    ]
    p.add_tools(hover)
```

when the dataframe has the columns names as "name", sale_num" and "sale_rev".

Is there a way to use variable names rather than actual column names?
So, if I set

```
var_01 = "name"
var_02 ="sale_num"
var_03 = "sale_rev"
```

How do I use something like:

```
('name of salesperson','@var_01')
```

rather than the corresponding

```
('name of salesperson','@name')
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
var_01 = "name"
var_02 = "sale_num"
var_03 = "sale_rev"
```

Then:

```
('name of salesperson','@' + var_01)
```

That will substitute things *on the Python side of things*, it will immediately generate:

```
('name of salesperson','@name')
```

because that's what's how standard Python string concatenation works, and then this is what gets sent to the browser.

If you are asking if there is some way to have this indirection cross over to the browser side (i.e. such that if you change the variable, the displayed content will update) the answer is ***No***, because the browser knows nothing at all about your Python code or variables.